# Getting error for Boost 1.71.0 library with Visual Studio 2019 on windows 10

Tags: c++, boost, windows-10, visual-studio-2019

I am using the latest Boost library version(1.71.0) with Visual Studio 2019 on Windows 10 but I am getting the error while compiling the example code. Is Boost 1.71.0 version compatible with visual studio 2019?

Installation process:

> 1) Downloaded the latest package from https://www.boost.org/
>
> 2) Extracted the package and ran the "bootstrap.bat" file in cmd.
>
> 3) Ran ./b2
>
> 4) Provided the path of created library and include folder in visual studio.
>
> > Include Dir: C:\libraries\boost_1_71_0
> >
> > Lib Dir: C:\libraries\boost_1_71_0\stage\lib

Error:  **fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'boost/iostreams/tee.hpp':**

Comment: _"...Is Boost 1.71.0 version compatible with visual studio 2019?..."_? Yes.  You have configured the include path incorrectly.  Add the directory structure and what path you added to MSVS to the question please.

Comment: @RichardCritten Hi, I have added the path information in the question.

Comment: I think your include dir is wrong. Does `C:\libraries\boost_1_71_0\boost\iostreams\tee.hpp` exist?

Answer (score 0):

you should Add include directory to your project:
Right click on The project then:

properties  ==>
C/C++    ==>   Additional include directory      ==> C:\libraries\boost_1_71_0\include